# The "Improve" button is confounded with the "Approve" button.

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

On [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335111/simplifying-sqrtxy-sqrtx3y-two-different-paths-different-results) I clicked on "Improve edit". Instead of being able to edit the page, I was instantly redirected to the question page with the proposed edit done, as if I had clicked on "Approve". This is the second time that that has  happened. The proposed edit fixed an obvious problem but neglected other edits that were obviously needed. (And were done after that by someone else.)

Comment: My guess is that the edit was accepted in the middle of your review(before you clicked the improve edit button)  so the review was completed which disallows any further action.

Comment: Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/831908) the edit in question? Because it looks like the edit was accepted by two other people.

Comment: One more request for clarification: when you were taken back to the question was the "edit" button usable or was it disabled?